# Dagger 2 Cross-Module Dependency

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

In my current project we have an `ApplicationComponent`, which holds various modules including a `NetworkModule`:

```
DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
    .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
    .apiModule(new ApiModule())
    .build();
```

I now want to setup a `UserServices` module that will provide at least a `UserServices` object, and that object requires some of the provides from the other modules for configuration. For example, the `NetworkModule` provides an `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level` that is used for other network calls in the app, and I would like to use the same in the `UserServices` calls.

Example from the debug version of the `NetworkModule`:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule extends BaseNetworkModule {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level getHttpLoggingInterceptorLevel() {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY;
    }
}
```

I want to keep the `UserServices` provide in its own module for the sake of encapsulation.

How do I set up the `UserServices` module so it can be included in the same component, and have access to the Provides in the `NetworkModule` for configuring the `UserServices` object that it provides?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out through a little trial and error. If the dependency module is not included in the `component` already then I can simply add the `includes` parameter to the `@Module` annotation:

```
@Module(includes= {
        NetworkModule.class,
        ApiModule.class
    })
```

In my case, the dependency module and some others are used in several places and all are needed independently in the `component` itself. Fortunately, it appears that Dagger will wire stuff up for me across modules in the same component. So I really didn't need to do anything special in this case -- Just this in the component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
            ApplicationModule.class,
            NetworkModule.class,
            SchedulerModule.class,
            ApiModule.class,
            UserServicesModule.class
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Network module as dependency to your UserServices module or add Network component as dependent component to UserServices component. If added as dependent component you'll have to mention the provider in Network component.